# hadoop2.6.0 sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh fail

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I'm following the [Hadoop official tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) to run Hadoop on a my machine in a pseudo-distributed mode.

I can use ssh to login in localhost without password:

```
admin@mycomputer:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0$ ssh localhost 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

4 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Feb  9 12:31:17 2015 from localhost
admin@mycomputer:~$
```

And I can also format the namenode without error, but I cannot start Hadoop with start-dfs.sh:

```
admin@mycomputer:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
root@localhost's password: 
localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
```

Why I'm still asked to provide root password while I can ssh into localhost without it?

I also tried:

```
sudo passwd
```

to reset the password, but later encounter the same permission denied error, it seems to me that this password is not the password for root@localhost. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't change the permission for the hadoop-2.6.0 folder. Give admin user permission to this folder and try to start.

Follow my below blog link : I provided steps in detail installing in Ubuntu by enriching from another blog.

http://gubendran.blogspot.com/2015/01/install-hadoop-in-single-node-linux.html